# Dotnetnuke - How to move my project to root directly?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have installed Dotnetnuke in a sub directory, and now i completed my project. How can i move my project to root directory? There are many hard coded links in my project. How can i change directory without any issues?

Please anyone help me!!!!

Comment: Let this be a lesson about the dangers of hard coded links.  Relative is best.

Answer (score 0):

The [Engage F3 module](http://www.engagesoftware.com/Products/Modules/Engage_F3.aspx) is free and allows you to do a search and replace in html modules to replace hard links.